# How to redraw a node with new options later in a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, pgfkeys

> What do you recommend in order to first define a node, with content, and later redraw its content with new options (overriding the way it was first drawn)?

Small pseudo-example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (M0) at (0,0) [scale=4.0] {\text{$M_0$}};
% Now imagine more tikzcode here and imagine that we need to redraw (M0), 
% but                        
% with half its size and opacity=0.5. Also imagine there are reasons
% why we did not define (M0) by "\node (M0) at (0,0) [scale=2.0,opacity=0.5] {\text{$M_0$}};" 
% in the first place.
% So we would like to be able to now write 
\redraw[scale=2.0,opacity=0.5] (M0);
% and have tikz redraw the content of the node (M0), 
% with the new  options, and nothing of the previous content visible.
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is somehow related to [How to access the content of a node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369981/how-to-access-the-label-text-of-a-node), at least in the sense that this is about getting at the content of (M0) by referring to its name only.

**Edit:** One reason why one would like to do so 
can be abstractly summarized thus: one would like to 
create a node by verbally specifying some of its properties.

For example, one would like to have:

```
\createnode[color=color_value,sizeofnode=sizeofnode_value,textinnode=textinnode_value] (nameofnode) at (positionofnode);
```

and similar thing. Using plain `\newcommand` does not provide such comforts, since one has to remember the *meaning* of the *position* of an argument. That is, while working one has to be able to answer questions like "What was the meaning of the ninth argument of my new command again?

I gather from the literature that to solve this one should use

**pgfkeys**

to create ones own customizable node-command, having options with telling names.

Therefore:

> Additional question. Do you agree that using **pgfkeys** is the way to go for the current problem, too?

Comment: Again, I'd use `\newcommand`, but I know you don't want that. Is this for a `beamer` presentation by the way? (Because it doesn't make sense for a normal document.)

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Thanks. It is not so much that I do not want to do it using \newcommand, but doing it that way _appears_ more complicated to me. It is not clear enough to me why that is so. I will describe why, provided I can explain it succinctly and clearly.

Comment: By the way, how to @ your pseudonym without using a copying functionality, i.e., how to @ it by typing only?

Comment: When you start typing `@Torbj..` you should see a small box with my username appear. Hit the Tab-key to complete it.

Comment: @PeterHeinig, if I understand correctly your question, you like to invent new syntax for shape options ... now you can write `\node[shape=rectangle, minimal width=<width>, ...] at (<coordinate>) {text}`. If your all nodes have something common, than you can this prescribe with `every node/.style={<common properties>}`, for example `draw`, `font` etc. Of course, there is other possibilities ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more common approach: use iterations

- start with basic code
- refine and compile again
- that's dynamic in itself.

The following example tries mimicking this process. Think of modifying your (M0) instead, or WITHOUT changing the coordinates, run by run:

- start small `\node        (M1) at (3, 0) {1. start small};`
- add a style `\node[sta]   (M2) at (3,-1) {2. add a style};`
- modify style until it's nice `\node[stb]  (M3) at (3,-3) {3. adapt style};`

So your style develops:

- from missing
- via `{draw=orange,text=red},`
- to finally `{draw=orange!80!yellow!50,text=red,minimum height=15mm,dashed,line width=3pt},`

If you also are unsure about the textual content of a node, you can e.g.:

- edit it in-place
- define a couple of macros in the preamble

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    sta/.style={draw=orange,text=red},
    stb/.style={draw=orange!80!yellow!50,text=red,minimum height=15mm,dashed,line width=3pt},
 ]
    % ~~~ your example ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (M0) at (0,0) [scale=4.0] {\text{$M_0$}};
 
    % ~~~ better ways to do it ~~~~~~~~~
    \node       (M1) at (3, 0) {1. start small}; 
    \node[sta]  (M2) at (3,-1) {2. add a style}; 
    \node[stb]  (M3) at (3,-3) {3. adapt style}; 
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```