# Change global tikz style from inside a tikz pic

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-pic, scoping

OK, guys. I had a strange idea and wanted to check with you if there is a way to do it. I couldn't get any insight from the pgfmanual, and I couldn't find similar questions either.

I wanted to use a tikz pic to create dynamic tikz pics. It would work as a "savebox" but calculated in "real time", if I could say so. Let me show you my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/meta/.style 2 args={
        code={
            \tikzset{
                #1/.pic={
                    \node[fill=#2]{};
                }
            }
            \pic{#1};
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[]at(0,0){meta={r}{red}};
    \pic[]at(1,0){meta={g}{green}};

    \pic[]at(2,0){r};
    \pic[]at(3,0){g};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code "almost" works. The pic inside of the meta draws correctly, but the outside pics give me an error like "I do not know the key /tikz/pic/r".

I assume that this is a scope problem, since the "r" key disappear after leaving the "meta" definition. Hence my question: is there a way to add a key to the global scope from inside of a local group? For regular LaTeX, we have macros like `\gdef` and `\xdef`.

Edit:

It is very easy to workaround this by using a regular macro instead of a tikz pic to create the dynamic style. Anyway, let's keep this as a challenge (if it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be done. With [@percusse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371193/121799) you can globalize pgf keys.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/meta/.style 2 args={
        code={\begingroup\globaldefs=1\relax
            \tikzset{
                #1/.pic={
                    \node[fill=#2]{};
                }
            }
            \endgroup
            \pic{#1};
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[]at(0,0){meta={r}{red}};
    \pic[]at(1,0){meta={g}{green}};

    \pic[]at(2,0){r};
    \pic[]at(3,0){g};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```