# Assigning a numerical variable with Tikz pgfmathtruncatemacro

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, variable

I am struggling with some basic computations with Tikz and I have a problem assigning a value to a variable inside a local scope.

Consider the following MVCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycommand}
{
    \def\myvar{0};
    \def\myresult{3};
    \ifnum\myvar=0
    {
        \def\myresult{4};
        \draw (0,1) node {Test is true!};
    }
    \fi;
    \draw (0,0) node {myresult=\myresult !!!};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\mycommand
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Written that way, the "Test is true!" is printed, but the value of `myresult` stays to 3.

So I assume that the second `\def` command creates a new variable, whose scope is limited to the `if` block.
After searching a bit, it seems I can get out by defining the variable as "global", using the `\global` command:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}
{
    \def\myvar{0};
    \global\def\myresult{3};
    \ifnum\myvar=0
    {
        \global\def\myresult{4};
        \draw (0,1) node {Test is true!};
    }
    \fi;
    \draw (0,0) node {myresult=\myresult !!!};
}
```

That way, it works, although I am not sure this is optimal (`\global` seems to be a TeX command, and I've read many times that it's a bad idea to use low-level TeX commands inside a LaTeX source...)

But now, my real code is a bit more complicated, and inside the "if" bloc, its actually a `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` that is used.
Say something like:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}
{
    \def\myvar{0};
    \global\def\myresult{3};
    \ifnum\myvar=0
    {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresult}{4}
    }
    \fi;
    \draw (0,0) node {myresult=\myresult !!!};
}
```

Then I get the same problem as above: `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` seems to declare a new variable, as I stay with the value `3`...

And both

```
\global\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresult}{4}
```

or

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\global\myresult}{4}
```

fail to compile.

How can I get out of this problem ?

Comment: If I simply replace in your very first example `\def\myresult{4};` by `\xdef\myresult{4}` the result is as I think you want it. (Please note also that ordinary TeX commands like `\def` do not need a `;` in the end.)

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But I tried that in the last snippet (when using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`), and it still does not work (it stays with "3").

Comment: Of course not. You could in principle add `\globaldefs=1` **BUT DON'T DO THAT PLEASE**. Really, why can't you use `\xdef`? You could just add `\xdef\myresult{\myresult}` after `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresult}{4}` if you want to "broadcast" the result of a .`\pgfmathtruncatemacro` computation.

Comment: Got it, thanks ! Indeed, i didn't think about that. Consider adding this as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rather safe how one can "broadcast" results, i.e. make them available outside a group.

- In this case, you could just use `\xdef`. Is `\xdef` dangerous? Well, this depends on the context. Not if you pay attention not to redefine known macros. Whether or not someone ever bothered to provide a more fool-proof version of `\xdef` I don't know. In case of doubt, one should of course check with `\@ifdefined` whether a command is defined. If desired, I could try to cook up something along these lines, but there are others who can do that much better, so you might want to ask a separate question on this.
- If you do a computation with, say, `\pgftruncatemacro` you could broadcast the result with something of the sort `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresult}{4}\xdef\myresult{\myresult}`
- There exist situations, e.g. when playing with pgfkeys, when you cannot just use `\xdef`. In these you could play around with [`\globaldefs`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371193/121799). However, I stress that I do not recommend doing this unless you are absolutely sure of what you're doing. (I used it once in an answer, but it really caused problems when the OP started to modify it, so I will be very very reluctant to go that route.

Here's an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycommand}
{
    \def\myvar{0}
    \def\myresult{3}
    \ifnum\myvar=0
    {
        \xdef\myresult{4}
        \draw (0,1) node {Test is true!};
    }
    \fi
    \draw (0,0) node {myresult=\myresult !!!};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\mycommand
\end{tikzpicture}

\renewcommand{\mycommand}
{
    \def\myvar{0}
    \global\def\myresult{3}
    \ifnum\myvar=0
    {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresult}{4}
        \xdef\myresult{\myresult}
    }
    \fi
    \draw (0,0) node {myresult=\myresult !!!};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\mycommand
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great in depth answer! I'll stick to exporting the result of the tikz-pgf computation with an `\xdef`. My LaTeX knowledge is increasing every day, thanks to people like you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your initial code was almost correct.  The problem was triggered by too many unnecessary but harmful semicolumns.

*Note that final semicolumns are used only to end TikZ command lines.*

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{%
  \def\myvar{0}
  \def\myresult{3}
  \ifnum\myvar=0 \def\myresult{4}{
    \draw (0,1) node {the test is {\color{blue}True}};
  }
  \fi
  {
    \draw (0,0) node {and \textit{myresult} is \myresult};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \mycommand
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Argh! You forgot to match your answer to *"no semicolons after `\def{...}`"*

Comment: @ AndréC: I have forgotten to erase them.  Thanks.