# forest - Change the color of the nodes after their creation by using their automatic name

Tags: formatting, forest

I have tried to use the solution given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559441/6880) to act on nodes of a `forest` tree but the solution does not work with automatic names given by `forest` to the nodes : see the MN(ot)WE below.

Is there a way to fix this ? If not what makes things going wrong ? A catcode problem ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\tikz@fig@main#1{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname labeltextof@\tikz@fig@name\endcsname{#1}%
  \iftikz@node@is@pic%
    \tikz@node@is@picfalse%
    \tikz@subpicture@handle{#1}%
  \else%
    \tikz@@fig@main#1\egroup%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand\labeltextof[1]{\csname labeltextof@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\aftercolorof}[2]{% #1 is the color, #2 us the node
  \path (#2.center) node[#1] {\labeltextof{#2}};
}

\newcommand{\changetxt}[2]{% #1 the node, #2 the text
  \path (#1.center) node[white, fill=white] {\labeltextof{#1}};
  \path (#1.center) node[black] {#2};
}


\begin{document}

\section{OK}

\begin{forest}
    [
        [$A$, name = nA
            [$B$, name = nB]
            [$C$, name = nC]
        ]
        [$D$, name = nD]
    ]
    \aftercolorof{red}{nA}
    \aftercolorof{blue}{nD}
    \changetxt{nB}{...}
    \changetxt{nC}{?}
\end{forest}


\section{KO}

\begin{forest}
    [
        [$A$
            [$B$]
            [$C$]
        ]
        [$D$]
    ]
    \aftercolorof{red}{!1}
    \aftercolorof{blue}{!2}
    \changetxt{!11}{...}
    \changetxt{!12}{?}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands such as `\aftercolorof{red}{!1}` don't work because `!1` is *not* the automatic name given to the node by forest. Those names are of form `node@N`, with `N` increasing in the order forest parses the bracket representation of the node. In the second tree, `\aftercolorof{red}{node@3}` colors `A` red.

`!1` is a *relative node name*: an instruction of how to reach some node starting from another node. For example, in OP's `\aftercolorof{red}{!1}`, we start at the root node (all TikZ code following the tree specification is attached to the root node; and there is no node name in front of `!`) and then move to its first child, `A`.

So to make OP's code work as intended, we need to make `\aftercolorof` and `\changetxt`
accept relative node names. This is easiest to do by redefining `\labeltextof`, as shown below, but be warned: the code contains forest's internal command `\forest@nameandgo`. This command changes forest's current node, so the name (or any other option) can then be accessed via `\forest(e)option`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\labeltextof[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \forest@nameandgo{#1}%
  \edef\tempnodename{\foresteoption{name}}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \csname labeltextof@\tempnodename\endcsname
}
\makeatother
```

P.S. Forest computes the position of the second level nodes using the original text (`B` and `C`), so "changing" the node text by `\changetxt` might result in a sub-optimal tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining things. I love a lot the `forest` and its `trees`. ;-)