# Tikz changing node background colour

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

Following the answer to [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369981/how-to-access-the-label-text-of-a-node), I am using the Milsymb library and changing the foreground colour.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{milsymb}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\tikz@fig@main#1{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname labeltextof@\tikz@fig@name\endcsname{#1}%
  \iftikz@node@is@pic%
    \tikz@node@is@picfalse%
    \tikz@subpicture@handle{#1}%
  \else%
    \tikz@@fig@main#1\egroup%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand\labeltextof[1]{\csname labeltextof@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\aftercolorof}[2]{% #1 is the color, #2 us the node
  \path (#2.center) node[#1] (#2-2) {\labeltextof{#2}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (nA) {\tikz{\MilLand[faction=friendly,monochrome,echelon=division,main=armoured]{}}};
\aftercolorof{red}{nA}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces red foregound colour.

[image]

How do I also change the node background colour (ie the light grey above, not the white image background)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fill=...` key (please be aware that nesting tikz pictures is not recommended and can have funny side effects.):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{milsymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (nA) {\tikz{\pgfsetstrokecolor{red}\MilLand[faction=friendly,monochrome,echelon=division,main=armoured,red,fill=green]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The location key allows positioning without nesting: `\coordinate (nA) at (0,0); \pgfsetstrokecolor{red} \MilLand[faction=friendly, echelon=division, main=armoured, red, fill=green](nA)`.

Comment: It says command undefined when I try `\coordinate` (and I seem to need the `{}` at the end, which you have omitted).

Comment: @TomasBy The syntax from @ JasperHabicht works fine for me, no `{}` at the end. Which error do you get?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Fun coincidence to meet you at that github repository :) Seems you had the same problem as me while looking into this question :)

Comment: Something about fonts. I was getting one error for each `\MilLand` (approximately, I had the impression) and they disappeared when I added the brackets.

Comment: Well, I still have the `\MilLand` commands in the matrix, so that may be the difference.

Comment: @TomasBy `\MilLand` (and all the other macros defined by the package) have `o D(){0,0} d() g` as argument type definition, so it is safe (and maybe also necessary sometimes, depending on the context) to add one pair of `{}` at the end of these macros (if no other argument is given instead).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Wow, the package author was quick! Maybe we should suggest that they add some way to style the line colors of the symbols ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes, very quick response! I'm not sure if a way to adjust line colours is that necessary. As far as I understand it, it will adapt to the surrounding text colour, so one can use anything from `\color{...}` to `\pgfsetstrokecolor{...}` to change it.